# Adobe Air for IOS/Android stuck publishing - 00:05 seconds remain

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am trying to publish an AIR fla for both iOS and Android using Flash Pro CS6, but it keeps getting stuck at 5 seconds remaining (and this same .fla exports just fine for someone else). This occurs for publishing for App Store, AdHoc, and Quick Device Testing.

I have tried different versions of the AIR SDK (3.2, 3.5 and 3.9), tried different versions of the Java 1.6 JDK, rebuilt certificates... basically tried everything I can think of, but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know of any circumstances that can possibly cause this to happen?

Comment: What does their customer service say?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to increase the memory available to Java.
[Increase heap size in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java)
Are you loading multiple SWFs?
http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/packaging-ios-with-many-swf-files-ad-hocapple-store-gives-outofmemory-error
General packaging help (although, it sounds like you've got it figured out):
http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/packaging-applications-air-ios.html

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Much appreciated! It looks like I managed to figure out a workaround, yet I still have no idea why it would be happening in the first place. The trick was to force Java to run in headless mode, so it wouldn't stall waiting for input. Not a clue why, but at least I can get back to actually being productive :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to find a workaround at least (I outlined here: http://forums.adobe.com/message/5804922#5804922) but it appears the solution was to force Java to run in headless mode.

This is somewhat inelegant, but it got it working for me at least (although I don't know what the impact will be yet on other Java programs I'm running)...

It seems that if Java is invoked without the 'headless' option, it can get stuck waiting on keyboard/mouse input, so I wondered if something similar could be happening here.

Without knowing exactly how to change the java options used by AIR specifically, I tried a brute-force method... namely replacing /usr/bin/java with a script that invokes Java with headless mode enabled:

1. Rename the original java binary: `sudo mv /usr/bin/java /usr/bin/java.org`
2. Create a new script: `sudo nano /usr/bin/java`
3. Add the following contents:

> `#!/bin/bash`
>
> `java.ori -Djava.awt.headless=true $JAVAOPT "$@"`

1. Give it the correct permissions: `chmod 755 /usr/bin/java`

Then I tried publishing again.... and lo and behold, it worked!!!